# In Python, how do I extract the domain portion of a URL?

Tags: django, python-3.x, parsing, uri

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I want to extract the domain portion of a URL.  Because "domain" may not be the right word, what I mean is if the URL is

```
www.yahoo.com
```

I would like to extract "yahoo.com".  If the URL is

```
www.indepednet.co.uk
```

I'd like to extract "independent.co.uk".  Not sure what the right terminology for this is.  I tried

```
ext = tldextract.extract(article_stat.article.url)
self.domain = ext.domain.lower()
```

but this only extracts one word.  In the first example, it only extracts "yahoo".  What is the proper way to extract the domain?

Comment: What you want may not be so trivial. For www.indepednet.co.uk you expect indepednet.co.uk, but for subdomain.website.com you expect website.com right?

Comment: Yes, right.  Is "domain" the right term I should be using here?

Comment: AFAIK yes, but the package you use behaves differently than what I know. With that package, "ext.domain.lower() + '.' + ext.domain.suffix.lower()" should give what you need

Comment: Sorry, it should be "ext.domain.lower() + '.' + ext.suffix.lower()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [suffix](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract#tldextract).

To do what you are trying to do, try this:

```
ext = tldextract.extract(article_stat.article.url)
self.domain = ext.domain.lower() + ext.suffix.lower()
```

It also looks like you can replace the second line with `self.domain = ext.registered_domain`